# openMP chunk and cache size

Tags: caching, fortran, openmp

I have a simple Fortran code which perform matrix multiplication and it is parallelized with OpenMP like this

```
!$OMP PARALLEL DO PRIVATE(...) SHARED(...) SCHEDULE(STATIC,N/128)
```

To make chunk size relatively large and number of chunks multiple of number of processors (4,8,16,etc.)

However, when matrix size goes really big, it seems more logical to set chunk size smaller than cache size (at least, it is worth to try). Is there a simple way to write a portable code which takes into account processor cache size? Or it is not supported by OpenMP?

Comment: I suggest you set up a small test at the beginning of your program. It would run a scaled-down version of your task for several chunk sizes and determine the optimal one based on the wallclock time.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on your algorithm and your problem. I suggest you to look for so called tiled algorithms and loop over tiles you setup yourself to have the right size. I use something like this for finite difference stencil computations:

```
   !$omp do
   do bk = 1,nz,tilenz
    do bj = 1,ny,tileny
     do bi = 1,nx,tilenx
      do k = bk,min(bk+tilenz-1,nz)
       do j = bj,min(bj+tileny-1,ny)
        do i = bi,min(bi+tilenx-1,nx)
          do something with array element A(i,j,k) and its neighbours
```

where `tilenx`, `tileny` and `tilenz` are the `x`,`y` and `z` dimensions of the tile.

There are more advanced ways how to organize the computation in the literature.

Comment: I would really like to play with different tile sizes. The problem, however, is that from the benchmarks I know that memory bandwidth is the bottleneck of the algorithm and to play with numbers I have to take into account processor cache size and layout. Which I don't know how to do in a portable way.

Comment: But this is exactly the thing you do for memory bandwidth limited problems! The whole point of tiling is to concentrate your thread on a small part of memory at one time - the tile - that fits into the cache.

Comment: For the memory bandwidth problem you break continuous memory into pieces as small as possible? You really do this?

Comment: No, you reuse the once loaded piece of memory as much as possible without referencing other parts. It is quite similar to usage of shared memory on GPU accelerators. Read some literature http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_tiling https://www.google.com/search?site=&source=hp&q=tiling+algorithms+cache+reuse .

Comment: Citation from wikipedia: "It is not always easy to decide what value of tiling size is optimal for one loop because it demands an accurate estimate of accessed array regions in the loop **and the cache size of the target machine**". The question was about how to get the size of the cache from the inside of the portable code.

Comment: It cannot be done from Fortran portably. You can call system specific routines. It is normal to optimize the parameters for the machine you are using. For usual Intels just go with 32 KB.

Comment: I checked, the N/128 approach is faster (~1%) than something around 32KB in my case. However, thanks for the discussion: it was helpful.